# How to see registered users in kamailio server?

Tags: sip, kamailio

I am very much new to Kamailio server . I found  out that the command to add users is 
"./kamctl add  ". But how can we find out the number of registered users or how can we know the number of authenticated users ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you look for active users (i.e., those registered with a SIP phone at that moment):

```
kamctl ul show
```

The above command will print the list of records in user location table from Kamailio memory.

If you look for provisioned users (i.e., users having a subscriber profile):

```
kamctl db show subscriber
```

The above command will print the content of database table subscriber where user profiles are stored.

Answer (score 3):

Just to see list of all online users you can run command:

```
kamctl online
```

If you want details of online users such as Expires, Callid, User-Agent, Last-KeepAlive, Last-Modified then use:

```
kamctl ul show
```